# Kafka Producer without key serializer

Tags: apache-kafka, serialization

I have a kakfa producer where I do not need to serialize a key, just the values. But the producer config requires the "key.serializer" setting.

```
Map<String, Object> producerConfig = new HashMap<>();
producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
```

I find it confusing when there is a random setting configured that is actually not used.

Is there a way to not set the "key.serializer" setting to signal that there is no key serialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option to indicate that the key will be `null` and `key.serializer` is not needed.

`KafkaProducer` doesn't know if the `ProducerRecord` that will be passed has key and/or value are set to `null`, so serializers have to be passed.

It is not possible to send a message without the key.
Even if you use following constructor: `ProducerRecord(String topic, V value)`. Behind the scene it sets a key (`null`):

```java
public ProducerRecord(String topic, V value) {
    this(topic, null, null, null /* key */, value, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is unfortunate. Would be nice in future versions. The only thing to indicate it for me is using the Producer with `private Producer<Void, Object> kafkaProducer;`

Answer (score 3):

**Kafka broker stores byte arrays**. So I think you must serialize.

Message of a Topic from a producer should be turned into bytes arrays(byte streams, streams of bytes) and stored in the partition of a broker. And then it gets de-serialized to go to Consumer.

And message is a key, value pair. so both key and value are required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but it still pops up on top of a Google search for similar topics, so just for completeness:

There is a VoidSerializer and a corresponding VoidSerde:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.VoidSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.VoidSerde;
```

Use, for example, like this:

```
properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, VoidSerializer.class);
```